# Is there a way to to print the component raw code before rendered to the screen in Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, components, document

I am trying to build an angular UI component lib doc without using any  third party document library like typedoc etc and found out it's hard to print out the raw component code example to screen, for example if I try:

```
<pre><code><some-component></some-component></code></pre>
```

The `<some-component>` will be rendered instead of showing the code.
I generated an example here https://plnkr.co/edit/baaNxRX1K1H8ry9pwfBU?p=preview
As you see, I tried to get the raw dom from the `<ng-content>` in `<example-component>` and the `<child-component>`is already rendered in raw dom which is not what I want.

Is there any way to print out the raw component code without putting it into a string like:

```
let codeString = '<child-component></child-component>'
```

Thank you!

Comment: You want to show the template or the component's class code?

Comment: I want to show the component's class code I think.For the example above, I literally just want to show `<child-component></child-component>`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the selector, just go with

```
<code>{{ '<child-component></child-component>' }}</code>
```

Interpolated strings are not rendered as HTML and/or Angular syntax, they are just presented as is.

As to showing the component's class' code.... Though, I do not think it is entirely impossible (though you can probably show the compiled JS, not the original TypeScript code), but I think the safest and easiest solution is to just copy-paste the code into a string and interpolate it.

Comment: Hi I've updated the plnkr, and it didn't work, the component still got rendered this way. Angular, errrrrrrrrrr

Comment: Wow, this is interesting! I mean, this should be an issue with Angular. Why would it treat interpolated inline strings as valid HTML? This is really weird. Well, anyway, you can try to create a pipe, for example, to make sure the string is treated as safe text, for example.

Answer (score 0):

```
<code [innerText]="'<child-component></child-component>'"></code>
```

If you're project is built with webpack you can get the component's code with the `raw-loader`:

```
@Component({
    template: `
        <code>{{ componentString }}</code>
    `
})
export class AppComponent {
  componentString = require('!!raw-loader!./some.component.html');
}
```

For syntax highlighting use [`prismjs-loader`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prismjs-loader). Here's a [demo project](https://github.com/Denhai/prismjs-angular-demo).

Comment: Thank  you, that will work, but now I need to figure out how to load that piece of string dynamically into a component in Angular 5, any advices on that? Thank you!

Comment: Hi Hayden, is there a way to use raw-loader with ng cli?